# GIT Checkout more than one branch at single shot

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Currently I am working on merging the sprint tickets branch by branch (Each story have a individual branch). All the developers have created a branch for their stories and merged their changes / impacts to their respective branches.

I have taken `git pull` and got all the new branches in my repository

```
Ex:

 * [new branch]      DEV-933 -> origin/DEV-933
 * [new branch]      DEV-950 -> origin/DEV-950
 * [new branch]      DEV-967 -> origin/DEV-967
 * [new branch]      DEV_904 -> origin/DEV_904
```

Now I need to merge these branches to Q.A branch as below (current branch is `QA_sprint_1.11`),

```
git merge DEV-933
```

but i am getting an error like `

> fatal: 'DEV-933' does not point to a commit

`

That means the branch `DEV-933` exists only in origin and not in my local git server. So i have checkout the branch `DEV-933` to my local server and tried the git merge and its working fine.

**ISSUE** : Currently i am having four branches from dev, but some times i may have 10 branches per sprint at that time i cannot go and check out each branch one by one for merging.

> Is there is any other way to accomplish the above task in a single command
>   OR step in GIT.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `git fetch` to grab all of the new branches, before merging?

Comment: Yes git fetch is also working like git checkout

Comment: You should also read the section titled [Git Branching - Remote Branches](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html) in the on line git book.  You don't need a local tracking branch for each "remote branch" (see [Nevik Rehnel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21302809/1256452)) but you should understand what a "remote branch" means, and the chapter should help.

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch` (and, by extension, `git pull`) tell you in their output:

```
* [new branch]      <branchname on remote> -> <branchname in your clone>
```

That means, if you have not set up a local tracking branch and don't want to do so, you can merge upstream branches into your current branch with

```
git merge <branchname in your clone>
```

where the branchname is taken from the `git fetch/pull` output.

You can also get a list of all branches in your clone, including "remote branches" (the ones created/updated by fetching) by using

```
git branch -a
```

---

**TL;DR:** You can just use

```
git merge origin/DEV-933
```

and so on